# CSS background-color Issue

Tags: html, css, background-color

I just have a header div into this div there is a navbar and after that there is some content i just gave that header div a background color but that background doesn't cover the hole screen width i just wanna that background cover the hole screen width but there is white space in the left,top and right
and here is the html code :

```
<!--Start header section-->
<div class="header">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="top-nav">
        <h1>Apptastico</h1>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="photos/iPhone.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="web-design">
            <h1>We design iOS apps</h1>
            <h4>Ut In Nulla Enim. Phasellus Molestie Magna Non Est Bibendum Non Venenatis ut In Nulla Enim. Phasellus Molestie.</h4>
            <p>Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu 
            tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim.
             Phasellus molestie tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat.
             </p>
            <input type="submit" value="Request qoute">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--End header section-->
```

and here is css code

```
.header{
    background-color: #4b5a65;
    height: 505px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

and that's the result which appear in the browser screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply

```
body{
  margin:auto;
}
```

See snippet below

```css
.header{
    background-color: #4b5a65;
    height: 505px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
body{
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<!--Start header section-->
<div class="header">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="top-nav">
        <h1>Apptastico</h1>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="photos/iPhone.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="web-design">
            <h1>We design iOS apps</h1>
            <h4>Ut In Nulla Enim. Phasellus Molestie Magna Non Est Bibendum Non Venenatis ut In Nulla Enim. Phasellus Molestie.</h4>
            <p>Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu 
            tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim.
             Phasellus molestie tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat.
             </p>
            <input type="submit" value="Request qoute">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--End header section-->
```

Comment: any more why i should put margin : auto in body section please ?

Comment: check this out, it is more detailed http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-margin-auto/

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your background is not taking entire screen. You should mention background to take entire width.

> background-size: cover;

Comment: I think the problem is *body* element is not reset.

Comment: what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <img src="photos/iPhone.jpg" alt="" />

 <input type="submit" value="Request qoute" />
```

Usually when I put an image or input tag on the page, it comes with those slashes at the end. This may or may not make a difference.

Same with the alternative text for that image. Try putting any random word in there.